# Checking for cookie: SyntaxError: Unexpected token u

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to see whether a cookie key is set:

```
if ($cookieStore.get('user')){
    $scope.session.user = $cookieStore.get('user');
    console.log($scope.session.user);
  }
```

An I get the error on the first line. This looks simple, so what am I doing wrong?

Full error:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token u
    at Object.parse (native)
    at Object.fromJson (http://localhost:8000/vendor/angular/angular.js:1139:14)
    at Object.get (http://localhost:8000/vendor/angular/angular-cookies/angular-cookies.js:172:34)
    at new <anonymous> (http://localhost:8000/js/main.js:44:33)
    at invoke (http://localhost:8000/vendor/angular/angular.js:3966:17)
    at Object.instantiate (http://localhost:8000/vendor/angular/angular.js:3977:23)
    at http://localhost:8000/vendor/angular/angular.js:7281:28
    at http://localhost:8000/vendor/angular/angular.js:6670:34
    at forEach (http://localhost:8000/vendor/angular/angular.js:332:20)
    at nodeLinkFn (http://localhost:8000/vendor/angular/angular.js:6657:11)
```

Comment: Something is stored in your cookie wrong. Can you paste your cookie?

Comment: In the cookie, I have `user=undefined`. I thought that the if statement would return false.

Comment: First line meaning what, the `if` statement? I don't see how--the JS is syntactically correct.

Comment: Yes, the if statement. I've uploaded the full error.

Comment: How did you set the cookie value in the first place? It looks like it's trying to parse, literally, `{ "user": undefined }`

Comment: The cookie was removed with `$cookieStore.remove('user');`, leaving it undefined.

Answer (score 2):

This was asked a year ago, but I just got the same error today.

All I did to resolve this was basically to clear my browser's cookies, and the error went away.

Comment: Even i was facing the above issue. I Cleared my browser cache and it worked fine for me

Comment: You just saved me from another 2 hours of headache, after spending 3 hours trying to figure this out. Thank you!